# how can i specify the resources that can be used for particular resolution

Tags: android

I need to provide  specific  resources say images for Particular resolution say 240 * 432

How can i do that without using -large extension(is der something like layout 240*432 ??)

regards,
Kariyachan

Comment: Iam happy to hear that if there is no way to do that...!   -:)